# What is the Fastest Way to Find the First Formula in an Excel Range with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any quicker method than using a for loop to find the first instance of a formula in a cell?

```
For Each dc In .Worksheets("testWS").Range(searchRange)
    If dc.hasFormula() = True Then
        formulaRow = Split(dc.Address, "$")(2)
        formula = dc.formula
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)`?

Comment: using a variant array of formulas would probably be a bit quicker if you're going to loop... `arr = range(searchRange).formula` as opposed to `.value`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No loop needed - use [`Range.SpecialCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells). Include error handling since there may be no cells with formulas.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim formulaRng As Range
Set formulaRng = .Worksheets("testWS").Range(searchRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not formulaRng Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print formulaRng.Cells(1).Row
    Debug.Print formulaRng.Cells(1).Formula
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Function FindFirstFormulaRow(ByRef rng As Range) As Long

    Dim arrFormulas As Variant

        Set arrFormulas = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)    
        Set rng = arrFormulas

            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                FindFirstFormulaRow = Split(rng.Cells(1).Address, "$")(2)
                Set rng = rng.Cells(1)
            End If
End Function`
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It returns the row of the first cell of the range you passed in that contains a formula without a loop. arrFormulas contains all the range SpecialCells  and arrFormulas(1) is the first formula cell